# Looking for offline solution for real time transcription (SpeechToText and speaker diarization)

Tags: speech-to-text, speaker-sgmentation

I'm looking for offline solutions to transcribe meetings between 2 or 3 people. I've found several offline transcribing tools but they don't differentiate between voices.

In addition, I need to transcribe meetings that can be around 1 hour long and the transcript needs to be ready in 5 minutes. Most offline tools that transcribe and assign voices take much longer than 5 minutes to transcribe and diarize the audio. So recording and then transcribing might not be a good option.

I've seen several solutions with whisper like:

https://github.com/davabase/whisper_real_time
https://github.com/MahmoudAshraf97/whisper-diarization

But the first one doesn't do speaker diarization and the second one isn't live.

I know python so if someone can point me to the right way to approach this that would be great!